# SonarQube: source directory does not match package declaration

Tags: java, sonarqube

I'm having difficulty working out the correct properties for sonarQube for my project. The folder structure is as following:

```
mod/
  framework/
    Framework.java
  rebuild2/
    Rebuild2.java
sonar-project.properties
```

There isn't much yet in either java file but do have they do have package declarations (mod.framework and mod.rebuild2 respectively).

I've tried a variety of different ways to write the properties file but it always errors with "The source directory does not match the package declaration". It seems like it is expecting the folders to be mod.framework/ and mod.rebuild2/.

I've looked through the documentation on the main website but all their examples do not have package declarations. I've also searched through here but either the solutions do not work for this or they are maven/gradle configs.

Does anyone have any idea whether it is possible to set up the sonar-project.properties file for this situation?

```
# Required metadata
sonar.projectKey=mc:rebuild2
sonar.projectName=Rebuild 2
sonar.projectVersion=0.2

# The value of the property must be the key of the language.
sonar.language=java

# Encoding of the source code
sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8

sonar.modules=framework,rebuild2
framework.sonar.projectName=Framework
framework.sonar.projectBaseDir=mod
framework.sonar.sources=.
rebuild2.sonar.projectName=Rebuild 2
rebuild2.sonar.projectBaseDir=mod
rebuild2.sonar.sources=.
```

Comment: Perhaps you could provide the content of your sonar-project.properties?

Comment: Edited to add my current sonar-project.properties file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is something conceptually wrong in your configuration.

Either the 'Framework' and 'Rebuild 2' projects are separate modules (think sub-projects) that have separate source trees; or they are merely separate packages in the same source tree, in which case you can remove the lines below `sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8`.

Your configuration tries to define 2 modules in the same source tree, and I don't think this is supported by current analyzers, except using exclusions, e.g:

```
sonar.modules=framework,rebuild2
framework.sonar.projectName=Framework
framework.sonar.projectBaseDir=.
framework.sonar.sources=.
framework.sonar.inclusions=mod/framework/**
rebuild2.sonar.projectName=Rebuild 2
rebuild2.sonar.projectBaseDir=.
rebuild2.sonar.sources=.
rebuild2.sonar.inclusions=mod/rebuild2/**
```

See [Multi-module Project configuration](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Runner#AnalyzingwithSonarQubeRunner-Multi-moduleProject) in the SonarQube documentation.

Comment: I removed the modules and have let it run as a single project. It does run fine but it's not ideal. Unfortunately I am unable to split up the projects into completely separate source trees due to external limitations so I'll have to make do with it.

Comment: It's a long shot, but you could maybe try to configure your modules with `projectBaseDir=.` and define exclusions on each project, to have only the source you want.

Answer (score 1):

If Java file(say File.java) has package delacration like :

```
package com.abc.xyz;
```

for a file, It means that file should be inside folder structure like

```
com
   abc
      xyz
         File.java
```

But in your case may be, this rule is voided. And your code should not compile too.

Please check, this may be the case.

Comment: The code compiles fine. The package declaration and folder structure are as you described. Rebuild2.java has package declaration package mod.rebuild2; and folder structure mod/rebuild2/Rebuild2.java

Comment: Despite of suggesting that metrics and other artifacts are computed for classes, SonarQube does not deal with classes at all. Instead, source code hierarchy is built based on the directory structure (assuming that it reflects the package structure, which is not necessarily true).